# Take path from env var doesn't work properly in CMakeList.txt

Tags: cmake

I am working with CMakeList.txt file and need to set a path to my lib. Currently I do it this way:

```
set(pathToOpenCv D:\\OpenCV-android-sdk)
```

, but I would like to change this hardcoded path to relevant path. I order to do it I saved key value env var

```
OPEN_CV_PATH = D:\\OpenCV-android-sdk
```

[image]

and edited `CMakeList.txt`

```
set(pathToOpenCv ${OPEN_CV_PATH})
```

But I get an error :

```
Execution failed for task ':co_decoder_engine_android:externalNativeBuildDebug'.
> Build command failed.
  Error while executing process C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\ninja.exe with arguments {-C D:\co_repo\co_main\Tier1.0\co_FileCodec_Engine\DecoderEngineBuilder\co_decoder_engine_android\.cxx\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a decoder_engine_api decoder_engine_lib libcodec}
  ninja: Entering directory `D:\co_repo\co_main\Tier1.0\co_FileCodec_Engine\DecoderEngineBuilder\co_decoder_engine_android\.cxx\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a'
  [0/1] Re-running CMake...
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  -- Build files have been written to: D:/co_repo/co_main/Tier1.0/co_FileCodec_Engine/DecoderEngineBuilder/co_decoder_engine_android/.cxx/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a
```

Looks like `CMake` don't know how to convert env var value from key to actual value.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are reading cmake variable and expecting it to expand to the value of the environment variable.

> how to convert env var value from key to actual value.

[Read the environment variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/ENV.html).

```
set(pathToOpenCv $ENV{OPEN_CV_PATH})
```